# NSComboBox into NSAlert

Tags: objective-c, nscombobox, nsalert

First of all I'm kind of new in Objc. (so try to explain me like. . .  for dummies XD) 
Well my question is: Is there any way to show a NSComboBox inside a NSAlert? 
that's it! 
I've check the documentations, an it says that it is possible to show a NSTextView, but I'm wandering if anyone has done this before (with the NSComboBox), a code example would be really useful!

Thank's in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka!!!

is really simple, you just have to remember that NSButton, NSTextField, NSComboBox. . . (etc) inherits from NSView so, you just need to send the object you need into your NSAlert like this:

```
[specialtyAlert setAccessoryView:specialtyOptions];
```

where specialtyAlert is an instance of NSAlert, and specialtyOptions is an instance of NSComboBox (but it could be an instance of NSButton or any other GUI object).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read the documentation on `setAccessoryView:` and `layout` at [this URL](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html). I don't know if you can insert a combobox there and if you can somehow get a return from it.

Comment: I've already check the documentation, and it's not really useful for what I want to do but thank you anyway